# export 'default' (imported as Vue ) was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am new with this vue and I got this error when I try to run (npm run serve):

```
***WARNING Compiled with 4 warnings
warning in ./src/main.js
"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
warning in ./src/main.js
"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
warning in ./src/main.js
"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
warning in ./src/router/index.js
"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
```

App running at:

- Local: http://localhost:8080/
- Network: http://10.2.220.30:8080/***

index.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [{
        path: "/home",
        name: "home",
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "login",
        component: () =>
            import ("../views/login.vue")
    },
    {
        path: "/register",
        name: "register",
        component: () =>
            import ("../views/register.vue")
    }
];
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
});
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("jwt") == null) {
            next({
                path: "/"
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
export default router;
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const base = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:4000"
});

Vue.prototype.$http = base;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: Have you installed Vue as a dependency? If so, how exactly?

Comment: I used npm install vue --save

Comment: Did you install Vue 2 or Vue 3? Vue recently released 3.0.0, and it has a different syntax for initializing Vue. Which is why you might have issues with the syntax above.

Comment: Actually when I create a vue project, I selected the vue3 babel....

Comment: At first it works fine when I run npm run serve..but as I go through in this project I got this error, that's why I install vue using npm but then again I got the same error.

Answer (score 15):

Vue v3:

```js
import * as Vue from 'vue';
import * as VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
  // TODO
];

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

Vue.createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/index.html

Answer (score 3):

When you upgrade to vue v3 should upgrade vue-router to 'vue-router/next'
[Offical website](http://next.router.vuejs.org/)
and use this code instead to import the function

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
```

and remove

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all dependencies installed.

eg. install the router

`npm install vue-router@next --save`

Answer (score 1):

Type these commands in the project terminal

```
npm uninstall vue-router --legacy-peer-deps
npm install --save vue-router@3
```

It worked in my case the issue was due to vue-router version

https://blog.csdn.net/cxl1191628698/article/details/127352186