# "export" 'Vue' was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I recently upgraded to vue3 using vue-next and when I run `yarn serve` I get some warnings.

`import Vue from 'vue';`
causes this warning `"export" 'Vue' was not found in 'vue'`.

`import { createApp, h } from 'vue'` works fine!

**package.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "vue": "^3.0.0-beta.1"
  }
}
```

Similar threads:

- ["export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63768491/export-default-imported-as-vue-was-not-found-in-vue)
- [export 'default' (imported as Vue ) was not found in 'vue'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64039363/export-default-imported-as-vue-was-not-found-in-vue)

Answer (score 2):

You say you've recently upgraded to Vue 3. The `import Vue from 'vue'` syntax is no longer supported, since Vue has been restructured to support tree-shaking.

Instead of trying to use `Vue.function`, simply `import { function } from 'vue'` and use it directly.

This is documented in the migration guide here: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api-treeshaking.html#global-api-treeshaking

I'd recommend giving the rest of the migration guide (at least the breaking changes) a read-through as well. It's very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
if (process.client) {
  import Vue from 'vue'
}
```

For more clarification
https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined

Answer (score 0):

try importing with this.

```
if (process.client) {
  import vue from 'vue'
}
```